# AWS EC2 ssh not working properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am unable to ssh into my EC2 instance.

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I tried stopping and starting my instance, which worked, but I don't want to do this everytime I want to ssh.

Does anyone know how to get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unlikely to happen again as generally it is due to heavy Server Load

> Have also seen this happen when server was under heavy load from for example, brute force attack. You can Increase the amount of connections sshd can run ([source](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/can%27t-ssh-to-remote-machine-connection-closed-by-remote-host-267052/page3.html#post4958163)).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not facing the issue for now, but will go through the mentioned link if I encounter it again.

Comment: try to debug it from CloudWatch logs at the time when you were unable to connect and see if there was unusual activity and if you find it normal login to server and see its logs that would help.

Comment: Interesting document link. A few items that I did not know.